# replacing r variables with multiple or different values

Tags: loops, replace, missing-data

I have a dataframe (raw) that can have one variable (iv1) with NA's in it. I want to replace the NA with different random values from the distribution of existing scores within (iv1), not one single value. the sample size (n) can be anything - 100 to 1000.

I save the distribution to a new data frame (dbmi) because I want to keep raw and dbmi separate, and calculate the mean and SD of the existing values of iv1 within dbmi. The following code works but replaces all of the NA's with just one value. I think I need to set up a for loop? Some kind of loop that finds the next occurrence of an NA and runs the new 'rnorm' value and sticks it in and goes to the next and does it again etc etc but I cant figure out how to do that. Any help?

```
dbmi<-raw
attach(dbmi)
rawmean<-mean(dbmi$iv1,na.rm=TRUE)
rawsd<-sd(dbmi$iv1,na.rm=TRUE)


for (i in 1:n){
dbmi$iv1[is.na(dbmi$iv1)]<-rnorm(1,rawmean,rawsd)
}
```

Comment: dbmi<-raw
attach(dbmi)
rawmean<-mean(dbmi$iv1,na.rm=TRUE)
rawsd<-sd(dbmi$iv1,na.rm=TRUE)
new<-rnorm(num,rawmean,rawsd)

for (i in 1:n){
 dbmi$iv1[pull]<-new
 }

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved my own problem. I set up the variable locations [i] that had the NA's into a variable called 'pull', then I just created a new stream into a variable called 'new' I used this code to substitute.

```
dbmi<-raw
attach(dbmi)
rawmean<-mean(dbmi$iv1,na.rm=TRUE)
rawsd<-sd(dbmi$iv1,na.rm=TRUE)
new<-rnorm(num,rawmean,rawsd)

for (i in 1:n){
    dbmi$iv1[pull]<-new
    }
```